# about ant sshexec

Tags: ant

how to specify command in sshexec task of ant to execute an ant task on a remote server machine. like for example:

```
<sshexec host="somehost"
    username="dude"
    keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa"
    commandResource="to_run"/>
```

in above code what would be in the command attribute while trying to perform an ant task on a remote server machine, and also if the ant task is to deploy an application

please help me out on this one as the appache site is not of much help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You're question is rather large in scope. For example to "deploy" an application... What are you deploying to? Tomcat? Websphere?.... Very importantly, what have your tried already? For example when you run the sshexec command what sort of errors are you getting. Supply an example and this will encourage others to help you.

Comment: Use `scp` to deploy a script together with the application files and then use `sshexec` to execute the script.